# add a column to a dataset using a formula

Tags: python

let me rephrase my question:

I have the following dataset:

---

```py
data = {
    'globalId': {0: 4388064, 1: 4388200, 2: 4399344, 3: 4400638, 4: 4401765, 5: 4401831},
    'publicatieDatum': {0: '2018-07-31', 1: '2018-09-24', 2: '2018-08-02', 3: '2018-08-04', 4: '2018-08-05', 5: '2018-08-06'},
    'postcode': {0: '1774PG', 1: '7481LK', 2: '1068MS', 3: '5628EN', 4: '7731TV', 5: '5971CR'},
    'koopPrijs': {0: 139000.0, 1: 209000.0, 2: 267500.0, 3: 349000.0, 4: 495000.0, 5: 162500.0}
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)
```

---

Now, I want to add a column called `Gemeente`.

This can be retreived using the following formula:

```py
nomi.query_postal_code(["postcode"])
```

The postcode above should indicate the 4 numbers of the postcode within the postcode column.

I have 2 questions:

1. How can I add a code that calculates the `gemeente` for all rows in the above dataframe, based on the 'postcode', as specified above?
2. How can this code be written that it only selects the first 4 digits in the postcode column?

Apologies and thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
df["Gemeente"] = df.apply(lambda x:nomi.query_postal_code(x["postcode"]), axis=1)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).